# design on apple.com -- how to transition from one photo (color) to another?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, background

The image is taken from apple.com.

I'm wondering how to recreate this effect of transition from one photo to another (in particular, I want to transition into white background) as shown in the photo:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you're speaking about purely graphics, it's as simple as using the Gradient Tool, preferably on a new layer, with a white to transparent background, clicking and dragging to achieve the desired effect. It doesn't get any more complicated than that.

If you're wondering, however, how to achieve this in your own website development, you can do it by overlaying a new `div` with a `background-image` property defined to a gradient.

This [Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) is a fantastic tool for the job, and it gives you the CSS you need to create those gradients. You can then position the `div` wherever you need it, and by tweaking the gradient and div position, you can transition the image to white or even achieve a transition between two images, just like Apple does on their website.

Comment: This answer is pretty good, just to add to it. The key is also finding images with empty space at the top / bottom. Roads, grass, sky, ocean, etc... Things that are predominately one color.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, that's absolutely true. Image selection is also a key aspect to an overall appealing look. Thank you as well for the correction, that's right. The FAQs do allow these questions!